# Pass a list of objects of a class into another class c++

Tags: c++

Passing base class pointer into another classes constructor c++

I think it is easier to explain my problem if i give the context. I am making a battleships game, and have a board class, an abstract base class "Ship" and then derived classes for different types of ships. I want to change my program so that i can take a list of my ships, and import them into the board class so they can be placed on the board. I am storing the ships in a base class pointer, and trying to make the board class so that the constructor takes in a list of ships.
Here is what i have at the moment (with other functions and code excluded for brevity):

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>  // to use input and output streams
#include<memory> // to use smart pointers
#include<vector> // to use vectors
#include"Ships.h" // Ships and derived ships classes here but dont think its needed to include this for the question
class Board{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> bdata; // to hold the data about the board
    int rows, columns;
    std::vector<Ship*> shipslist;
public:
    Board(std::vector<Ship*> &list); // Constructor
    ~Board() {} // Destructor
};

Board::Board(std::vector<Ship*> &list) : rows{ 10 }, columns{ 10 }, shipslist{list}
{
    // irrelevant code here
}

int main()
{
    // Make vector of Ships
    std::vector<Ship*> ships;
    ships.push_back(new Destroyer('h', "A0"));
    // (Destroyer is a derived class of the abstract base class "Ship")
    Board BoardConfig(ships); // Here is where i want to create a board using a list of ships i have made
return 0;
}
```

I cannot get it to compile and at the moment visual studio
[is telling me this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtZKN.png)

I am not actually sure if this is even the best method. I was wondering whether i should maybe make another class "Game" that takes in a blank board, and a list of ships. Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thankyou.

Edit: tried to exclude things for brevity, will post everything here incase it makes it more obvious where the problem is:
here is main file:

```
// Aim is to create a battleships game. The current idea is to be a 1 player game.
// The computer will randomize the starting board, and the user will try to sink all ships in as few moves as possible
// High score will be saved and the user competes against themself.

#include<string>
#include<iostream>  // to use input and output streams
#include<utility>  // for use of std::pair , std::make_pair
#include<memory> // to use smart pointers
#include<vector> // to use vectors
#include"Board.h" // Header file with board class
#include"Ships.h" // Header file with Ship abstract base class, and derived classes for specific types of ship

// Function to validate a grid reference is in the correct format
bool ValidGridReference(std::string input){
    if (input.length() > 2 || input.length() < 2){
        std::cerr << "Location input must be of length 2 characters.\n";
        return false;
    }
    else{ // If input has length 2, then get to this stage
        // This could be a good place for template function with stoi and string to character @todo
        try{
            char Column = tolower(input[0]);
            if (!('a' <= Column && Column <= 'j')){
                std::cerr << "Column must be letter from A to J. \n";
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (...){
            std::cerr << "First character of location input must be a letter between A and J. \n";
            return false;
        }
        try{
            int Row = std::stoi(input.substr(1, 1)); //This means the substr is the first character after the first 1
            if (Row < 0 || Row > 9){
                std::cerr << "Row number must be between 0 and 9. \n";
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (...){
            std::cerr << "Second character of location input must be integer. \n";
            return false;
        }
    } return true;
}

/* Convert alphabetical character to grid number, here
charToGridIndex('a') == 0
....
charToGridIndex('j') == 9*/
int charToGridIndex(char c) {
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'J')
    {
        return c - 'A';
    }
    else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'j')
    {
        return c - 'a';
    }
    else
    {
        return -1; // Return -1 to indicate an invalid character
    }
}

// Function that makes user enter a grid location, and continues to prompt to re enter if they put anything else.
// This will be used in a player class most likely - just wanted to do something easy to write.... @todo
void InputLocation(){
    bool still_prompt = true;
    while (still_prompt)
    {
        std::string answer;
        std::cout << "Enter a grid location from A0 to J9" << std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin, answer);
        if (ValidGridReference(answer) == true)
            still_prompt = false;
    }
    // Now that we have a valid input that can be used, could return it.
}

// Function that makes user enter an option i or j, and continues to prompt to re enter if they put anything else.
bool ChoiceCheck(char i, char j){
    bool still_prompt = true;
    bool choice;
    while (still_prompt)
    {
        std::string answer;
        std::getline(std::cin, answer);
        if (answer.length() > 1){
            std::cout << "Input invalid. Enter " << i << " or " << j << ".\n";
            continue;
        }
        char ans = tolower(answer[0]);   // So that user can enter y or n in either lower or upper case
        if (ans == i){
            choice = true;
        }
        else if (ans == j){
            choice = false;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "Input invalid. Enter " << i << " or " << j << ".\n";
            continue;
        }still_prompt = false;
    }
    return choice;
}

// Game class takes in a config board, made using a list of ships, it has its own "playing board" which can be compared to the config board
class Game{
private:
    Board Configboard;
    std::vector<Ship*> ships;
public:
    Game() : Configboard(), ships() {};
    Game(Board const &b, std::vector<Ship*> &s);
};

// Parameterised Constructor
Game::Game(Board const &b, std::vector<Ship*> &s) : Configboard(b), ships(s)
{
    std::cout << "Game parameterized constructor called" << std::endl;
};

// Main program
int main(){
    bool repeat = true;
    while (repeat){
        // Make vector of Ships
        std::vector<Ship*> ships;
        ships.push_back(new Destroyer('h', "A0"));
        ships[0]->info();
        Board BoardConfig(ships);
        //Gameboard.DisplayBoard();  @todo maybe if im not using this function i should delete it
        BoardConfig(1, 5) = '7';
        std::cout << BoardConfig << std::endl;
        //InputLocation();
        std::cout << "Would you like to play again and try to beat your highscore? Press y to play or n to quit." << std::endl;
        repeat = ChoiceCheck('y', 'n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

here is Ships.h:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>  // to use input and output streams
#include<utility>  // for use of std::pair , std::make_pair
#include<memory> // to use smart pointers
#include<vector> // to use vectors

class Ship{
    friend bool ValidGridReference(std::string input);
    friend int charToGridIndex(char c);
public:
    virtual ~Ship(){ std::cout << "Base class destructor called" << std::endl; }
    virtual int length() = 0;
    virtual void info() = 0;
};

class Destroyer : public Ship
{
protected:
    int Shiplength; char direction; std::string name; std::string location; std::string status;
public:
    Destroyer(char d, std::string loc);
    ~Destroyer() { std::cout << "Destroyer destructor called" << std::endl; }
    int length() { return Shiplength; }
    void info() { std::cout << "Ship with name " << name << " of length " << Shiplength << " in direction " << direction << " at location " << location << " has status " << status << std::endl; }
};

// Parameterised Constructor
Destroyer::Destroyer(char d, std::string loc) : Ship(), Shiplength(5), direction(d), name("Destroyer"), location(loc), status(Shiplength, 'U') // U means unhit
{
    std::cout << "Destroyer Constructor called" << std::endl;
    if (Shiplength < 1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: trying to declare a ship with length < 1" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if (d != 'h' && d != 'v')
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: trying to declare a ship with direction other than h or v" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if (ValidGridReference(loc) == false)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: trying to construct ship in non existant position." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((d == 'v' && loc[1] + Shiplength > 10) || (d == 'h' && charToGridIndex(loc[0]) + Shiplength > 10))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: ship cannot be placed partly off the board." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

here is Board.h:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>  // to use input and output streams
#include<utility>  // for use of std::pair , std::make_pair
#include<memory> // to use smart pointers
#include<vector> // to use vectors
#include"Ships.h"

// Abstract base class used as an interface for all ships
class Board{
    //Friends for overloading output stream
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Board &b);
private:
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> bdata; // to hold the data about the board, (empty space, ship hit, ship unhit)
    int rows, columns;
    std::vector<Ship*> shipslist;
public:
    // Constructor
    Board(std::vector<Ship*> &list);
    // Destructor
    ~Board() { std::cout << "Board destructor called" << std::endl; }
    // Access functions
    char & operator[](int i);
    char &operator()(const int &i, const int &j) const;
    int getrows() const { return rows; }
    int getcols() const { return columns; }
    int length() const { return rows*columns; }
    //Move and copy 
    Board(const Board &b); //copy
    Board(Board &&b); //move
    Board& operator=(const Board &b); //copy assignment
    Board& operator=(Board &&b); //move assignment
};

// Constructor
Board::Board(std::vector<Ship*> &list) : rows{ 10 }, columns{ 10 }, shipslist{list}
{
    std::cout << "Constructor called" << std::endl;
    if (columns < 1 || rows < 1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: trying to declare a board with size < 1" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    bdata = std::make_unique<char[]>(rows*columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows*columns; i++)
        bdata[i] = '0';
}

// Copy constructor for deep copying
Board::Board(const Board &b)
{
    // Copy size and declare new array
    columns = b.getcols(); rows = b.getrows();
    if (b.length() > 0)
    {
        bdata = std::make_unique<char[]>(b.length());
        // Copy values into new array
        for (int i = 0; i<b.length(); i++)
            bdata[i] = b.bdata[i];
    }
}

// Move constructor
Board::Board(Board &&b)
{ // steal the data
    std::swap(columns, b.columns);
    std::swap(rows, b.rows);
    std::swap(bdata, b.bdata);
    b.columns = 0;
    b.rows = 0;
    b.bdata = 0;
}

// Assignment operator for deep copying
Board & Board::operator=(const Board &b)
{
    if (&b == this) return *this; // no self assignment
    // First delete this object's array
    bdata = 0; columns = 0; rows = 0;
    // Same code as constructor
    columns = b.getcols(); rows = b.getrows();
    if (b.length() > 0)
    {
        bdata = std::make_unique<char[]>(b.length());
        std::cout << "copy assignment\n" << std::endl;
        // Copy values into new array
        for (int i = 0; i<b.length(); i++)
            bdata[i] = b.bdata[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

// Move assignment operator
Board & Board::operator=(Board&& b)
{
    std::swap(columns, b.columns);
    std::swap(rows, b.rows);
    std::swap(bdata, b.bdata);
    b.columns = 0;
    b.rows = 0;
    b.bdata = 0;
    return *this;
}

// Overload output stream
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Board &b)
{
    // print board out
    os << "   A B C D E F G H I J" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < b.getrows() + 1; i++){
        os << i - 1 << "| ";
        for (int j = 1; j < b.getcols() + 1; j++){
            os << b.bdata[b.getcols()*(i - 1) + (j - 1)] << " ";
        }
        os << std::endl;
    }
    os << "Moves taken:" << " 10" << std::endl;   // @todo make these work
    os << "Ships sunk:" << " 0" << std::endl;
    os << "High Score: " << " 20 " << std::endl;
    return os;
}

// Overloaded element [] operator implementation
char & Board::operator[](int i)
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= rows*columns)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: trying to access array element out of bounds.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    return bdata[i];
}

// Overload () operator
char &Board::operator()(const int &i, const int &j) const
{
    if (i < 1 || j < 1 || i > rows || j > columns)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: tried to access grid reference that doesnt exist.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    return bdata[columns * (i - 1) + j - 1];
}
```

Comment: classes aren't objects.  You don't pass classes in a list, you pass objects.   Classes are descriptions, objects are the instances of the described thing.

Comment: You are constructing Board and using initializer list to initialize members: rows, columns and shipslist and it is probably trying to copy the vector of Ships and its content?. But since Ship is an abstract class it is unable to copy its contents as is. Attempt to rewrite your constructor to simply copy each Ship as pointer/reference.

Comment: Wow, that's a mountain of code. Please delete that and post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead. Remember that questions here should be *focused* on a *single* *specific* problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your `ship.h` code is (you need to post everything), but creating some simple versions, it seems to work fine:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>  // to use input and output streams
#include<memory> // to use smart pointers
#include<vector> // to use vectors

struct Ship{};
struct Destroyer : Ship {};

class Board{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> bdata; // to hold the data about the board
    int rows, columns;
    std::vector<Ship*> shipslist;
public:
    Board(std::vector<Ship*> &list); // Constructor
    ~Board() {} // Destructor
};

Board::Board(std::vector<Ship*> &list) : rows{ 10 }, columns{ 10 }, shipslist{list}
{
    // irrelevant code here
}

int main()
{
    // Make vector of Ships
    std::vector<Ship*> ships;
    ships.push_back(new Destroyer()); // simplified constructor call
    // (Destroyer is a derived class of the abstract base class "Ship")
    Board BoardConfig(ships); // Here is where i want to create a board using a list of ships i have made
return 0;
}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/z/r0ye_U

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have edited my post with the full code, incase it is then more obvious whats going wrong.